# pod COMMAND(setup, init, install) showing "Permission denied" error on Macbook Pro with OS X 10.10.5

Tags: macos, terminal, cocoapods

I'm getting "Permission denied" error when i am executing any command on terminal.
The macbook which I'm using is running on OS X 10.10.5, and also this macbook is provide by my company so it having some permission levels. But I made my login as admin login.
When i'm executing "pod setup —verbose" command I'm getting below errors

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:959:in `read': Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/specifications/terminal-notifier-1.6.0.gemspec (Errno::EACCES)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:959:in `load'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:644:in `block (2 levels) in each_spec'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:643:in `each'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:643:in `block in each_spec'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:642:in `each'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:642:in `each_spec'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:658:in `each_normal'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:669:in `_all'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:822:in `each'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:253:in `find_all'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:253:in `matching_specs'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:277:in `to_specs'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
from /usr/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
```

I tried almost all the solutions available, but I didn't get the solution. Please help he on this.

**Update**

If i use the commands with sudo i am getting below errors.

> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.9.1/lib/claide/command.rb:417:in `help!': [!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root. (CLAide::Help)

Usage:

```
$ pod COMMAND

  CocoaPods, the Cocoa library package manager.
```

Commands:

```
+ cache      Manipulate the CocoaPods cache
+ init       Generate a Podfile for the current directory.
+ install    Install project dependencies to Podfile.lock versions
+ ipc        Inter-process communication
+ lib        Develop pods
+ list       List pods
+ outdated   Show outdated project dependencies
+ repo       Manage spec-repositories
+ setup      Setup the CocoaPods environment
+ spec       Manage pod specs
+ update     Update outdated project dependencies and create new Podfile.lock
```

Options:

```
--silent     Show nothing
--version    Show the version of the tool
--verbose    Show more debugging information
--no-ansi    Show output without ANSI codes
--help       Show help banner of specified command
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:44:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/bin/pod:44:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
```

Comment: have you tried using sudo ?

Comment: @EugeneZhenyaGordin I tried with sudo, that also i am getting error. Please see the update part of the question to see the errors

Answer (score 0):

Try to update permission on CocoaPods

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods

sudo chown -R $USER ~/.cocoapods
```

Try running "pod install" and see if it fixed your problem.

If you still getting permission denied, try:

```
sudo chown -R $USER ./Pods
```

Also you might need to remove old podfile.lock before running pod install

Comment: I am getting this issue "chown: /Users/skuma921/Library/Caches/CocoaPods: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Pod Update you are trying to run, the original folder that was downloaded may not have given you read/write access.  Navigate to that folder in Finder and right click to get info.  Go to permissions and check to see that your user name is listed and have read/write access.  If not add your user name and give yourself the rights.